# How to stop till progress bar finishes in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a splash screen with progress bar ( using [react-native-progress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress) for progress bar). My goal is check user availability in this splash screen and redirect the user accordingly. I am using redux, so created a action to check if there is login token available.

My Redux action for logincheck:

```
export const loginCheck = (callback) => {

return async (dispatch) => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGIN_TOKEN);
    let userUid = await AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_UID);
    if(token && userUid) {
        dispatch({ type: VALID_LOGIN_AVAILABLE, payload: token });
        dispatch({ type: VALID_UID_AVAILABLE, payload: userUid });
        callback();
    }
    else {
        dispatch({ type: NO_VALID_LOGIN_AVAILABLE, payload: token });
    }
 }
};
```

So, I am storing token and uid from firebase to async when user login's. And used callback when user details available. So in the splash screen, when i receive a callback, i set state "isUserAvailable" as true else default false.

My goal is to, wait for progress bar to finish, and then redirect to Dashboard if isUserAvailable is true && progress bar === 1. Else user will be redirected to Signup screen.

My progress Bar Action Code:

```
export const progressBarLevel = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    this.progress = 0;
    dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: 0 });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.indeterminate = false;
       const interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.progress += Math.random()/5;
            if(this.progress > 1){
                this.progress = 1;
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            return dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: this.progress });
        },250)
    },500)
  }
}
```

And using props to get this progress data. So when it reaches to 1, the bar finished. And when bar finishes, the login check is performed and redirected. this is the whole process.

My ComponentDidMount code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loginCheck(() => {
        this.setState({ isUserAvailble: true})
    })

   this.props.progressBarLevel();
}
```

My componentDidUpdate code:

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
   if(this.props.progressed === 1 && this.state.isUserAvailble === true) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
   }
   else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpForm')
   }
```

}

Now whats happening is, the pages get redirected to SignUpForm even without finishing the progress bar, How to make componentDidUpdate to wait untill progress bar finishes ?

Kindly Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code would solve your problem. Here the assumption is you have isUserAvailable with you when progress bar finishes.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   if(this.props.progressed === 1) {
       if(this.state.isUserAvailble === true) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
       }
       else {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpForm')
       }
   }
}
```

One more observation you should not set State through a callback. You can use the userId state to check it.

One more point you should dispatch progress from login action and clear it when you finish check of user available with you. It is a cleaner approach to take.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks for the solution ! by the way, can i know why we should not setstate using call back ? And so you suggest me to combine progress and login action ? What difference it gonna make ?

Comment: And i am getting an error some time stating Attempted to transition from state `RESPONDER_INACTIVE_PRESS_IN to RESPONDER_ACTIVE_LONG_PRESS_IN, which is not supported. This is most likely due to Touchable.longPressDelayTimeout not being cancelled.` Any idea whats this ? out of 10 attempts, i am getting this for atleast 2 times !

Comment: Now i am facing another issue, as when i started to type something in singup form, the redux store get updates the value and thus, the singup form redirects to Dashboard. I think, the component is still mounted. How to unmount the component ? As once the page is redirected, there should not be any relation with this page !

Comment: Actually, when i tried your suggestion, of changing the call back to the state. Its acting weirdly, when i type something on signup page, the singup page again redirects to welcome page, the i clicked singup button again and then types again, then it goes back to signup page ! whats happening ?

Comment: Don't use UserId from store but you can set bool in store for isUserAvailable.